# Hydrogen gas tube in hydrogen spectrum experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, plasma-physics

Generally to detect the hydrogen spectrum people uses the hydrogen gas tube as a light source. Initially the gas is formed by molecular $H_2$ and since in the experiment we detect the atomic hydrogen spectrum  we can say that after some time the gas is formed by atomic hydrogen $H$. In the gas tube we have various process such as molecular dissociation (formation of $H$) , association (formation $H_2$), excitation and elastic scattering.

My question is , can the excess  atomic hydrogen in relation to the molecular hydrogen be explained by the fact that the  dissociation cross section $\sigma_d$ is superior to to sum of all the other cross section (association, excitation  and elastic scattering)?

Comment: Which other cross sections?

Comment: @ my2cts   I edited my question

Comment: You probably use rf to dissociate or there would be only H2.

Comment: what do you mean by "rf"?

Comment: Radiofrequency field.

Comment: The process is initiated by electron molecules scattering

Comment: Sure, you initially have to split molecules faster than you have them recombine. For a given energy input you eventually reach a steady state concentration of atomic hydrogen.

Comment: @ Jon Custer Do you mean that the dissociation cross section increases more than the others cross section  as we increase the system energy?. Could you give me some references ?

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. Initially there are no dissociated molecules. Putting energy in starts ripping some apart, but steady state occurs when the dissociation is balanced be reassociation. No change to cross sections needed, just rate balancing.